# dodge/displace/repel axis tick labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I want is probably not possible without a lot of work, but maybe someone has a solution.  I have a plot like the following (this is an oversimplified example of course) where I have tick labels that fall very close to each other:

```r
dd <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=c(-10,10.5,10.6,10.7),
                 z = LETTERS[1:4])
library(ggplot2)
gg1 <- ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(x=0, aes(xend=x, y=y, yend=y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=dd$y, labels=dd$z)
```

[image: plot with three tick labels (B, C, D) overlapping]

If I really want to I can export as SVG, dump it into Inkscape, and move the labels apart manually (even adding in little indicator lines connecting the labels with the precise y-axis positions):

[image: picture with B, C, D manually displaced]

It would be nice to be able to do something like this programmatically/automatically. I thought about:

- `ggrepel` package (only works on labels/text *within* the plot AFAIK)
- `directlabels` package (it has some placement options like "first.bumpup" that *might* be adaptable/hackable for this case)
- the `n.dodge` and `check.overlap` arguments to `guide_axis` as illustrated [here](https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-dodge-overlapping-text-on-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot2/) look useful and interesting, and they *almost* handle this case, but `n.dodge` dodges labels horizontally, which will get ugly if the labels are longer than a few characters ...

I would be happy enough with a `label.pos.nudge` argument that could be specified manually to displace the positions of the labels along the axis from their corresponding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025382/ggrepel-labels-outside-to-the-right-of-ggplot-area/56027661#56027661) (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot) letting me know about `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`, I made the following work (**note** that I had to change `geom_segment(x=0, ...)` to `geom_segment(x=-Inf, ...)` in the base example above, so that turning off clipping didn't mess things up).

```r
gg1 + coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(t=5.5, r=5.5, b=5.5, l=30, unit="pt")) +
  geom_text_repel(x = 0.85, aes(label = z, y = y),
                  direction = "y",
                  force_pull = 100,
                  hjust = -7,
                  xlim = c(0.8,1))
```

[image: graph with repelled points]

Note that this may require a fair amount of fussing with plot margins and the arguments of `geom_text_repel` (`force`, `force_pull`, `hjust`, `xlim`, etc.) to get it looking right ... I still haven't gotten my real plot just the way I want it, but it's getting close. (It's possible that the `x` and `hjust` values are redundant here ...)